# How to find prime numbers that are member of twin prime as well as member of cousin prime?

Tags: c, primes

I have to find the prime numbers from 1 to 100 that are in twin prime number members as well as cousin prime number members.

For example : 7 is a member of twin prime number as well as a member of cousin prime number.

and also, I have to find how many this kind of numbers are there from 1 to 100.

sample input and output :

```
start = 1
end = 100
```

output : 7 11 13 17 19 41 43 71

Explanation : twin primes in 1 to 100 are (3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31), (41, 43), (59, 61), (71, 73)
cousin primes in 1 to 100 are (3, 7), (7, 11), (13, 17), (19, 23), (37, 41), (43, 47), (67, 71), (79, 83)

SO 7 11 13 17 19 41 43 71 numbers are both in twin primes and cousin primes.

I have tried so far :

To check the twin numbers and cousin numbers I have done this loop

```
for(i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(i + 2))
        {
            if(isPrime(i+4) || isPrime(i+2+4))
            {
                count++;
                printf("%d %d %d %d\n",i, i+2, i+4, i+6);
            }
            i++;


        }
    }
    printf("\n");
```

but It doesn't give me the right result.

What to change to make it work?

the full code is given bellow:

```
int isPrime(unsigned long number)
{
      int i, nb, count, test,limit;
      test = count = 0;
      nb = number;
      limit = sqrt(nb) + 1;

      if(nb == 1)
      {
          return 0;
      }

      if(nb == 2)
      {
          return 1;
      }

      if (nb % 2 == 0)
              test = 1;
      else{
          for (i = 3 ; i < limit && ! test; i+=2, count++)
            if (nb % i == 0)
              test = 1;
      }
      if (!test)
              return 1;
      else
              return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int start, end;

    printf("Enter start: ");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    printf("Enter end: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    unsigned long i;

    for(i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(i + 2))
        {
            if(isPrime(i+4) || isPrime(i+2+4))
            {
                count++;
                printf("%d %d %d %d\n",i, i+2, i+4, i+6);
            }
            i++;
            //count++;

        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The number: %d",count);



    return 0;
}
```

I have used unsigned long so that I can use this program to find large number later.

Edit for the main function

```
int main()
{
    int start, end;

    printf("Enter start: ");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    printf("Enter end: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    unsigned long i;

    for(i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(i + 2))
        {
            printf("[ %lu , %lu ]\n", i, i+2);
            i++;
            count++;

        }
    }
    for(i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(i + 4))
        {
            printf("[ %lu , %lu ]\n", i, i+4);
            i++;
            count2++;

        }
    }
    printf("The number of twins: %d",count);
    printf("The number of cousins: %d",count2);


    return 0;
}
```

this main function gives twin primes and cousin primes. But I want to find the common numbers of those two. It's kind of confusing for me. I don't know what to do to find the common numbers.

Comment: Aside: I would use `unsigned long long` if you want a larger number than `int`, because `long` is not guaranteed to be any larger than `int` (and often isn't).

Comment: 7 is prime number but 7+2 it not: so are they twin according to your definition ? 5 and 5+2 are prime but 5+4 is not prime. I don't get it ...

Comment: @pifor isn't that `isPrime(7+2)` in the code?

Comment: Actually I knew how to find twin numbers and how to find cousin numbers. But I do not understand how to find the common numbers between  twin numbers and cousin numbers. That's why I was trying out.

Comment: @WeatherVane you got it the wrong way, int is guaranteed to be atleast 16bits while long is guaruanteed to be atleats 32bits.

Comment: @LeeDaehyun: you should post a full test case: for example if you enter start=2 and end=10 what is the expected output ?

Comment: @pifor I have edited the post. sample input and output :

start = 1
end = 100
output : 7 11 13 17 19 41 43 71

Explanation : twin primes in 1 to 100 are (3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31), (41, 43), (59, 61), (71, 73) cousin primes in 1 to 100 are (3, 7), (7, 11), (13, 17), (19, 23), (37, 41), (43, 47), (67, 71), (79, 83)

SO 7 11 13 17 19 41 43 71 numbers are both in twin primes and cousin primes.

Comment: i+4 cannot be a prime except for i = 7.

Comment: Prime numbers greater than 3 are all of the form 6n±1.  You can use that to limit your searches.  For example, after (3, 5) all twin primes are of the form (6n-1, 6n+1).

Comment: Please define: `twin prime` and `cousin prime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution (requiring additional memory - likely to be optimized) is to build the list of twins and cousins and to intersect these two list.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int isPrime(unsigned long number)
{
      int i, nb, count, test,limit;
      test = count = 0;
      nb = number;
      limit = sqrt(nb) + 1;

      if(nb == 1)
      {
          return 0;
      }

      if(nb == 2)
      {
          return 1;
      }

      if (nb % 2 == 0)
              test = 1;
      else{
          for (i = 3 ; i < limit && ! test; i+=2, count++)
            if (nb % i == 0)
              test = 1;
      }
      if (!test)
              return 1;
      else
              return 0;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long start, end;

    printf("Enter start: ");
    scanf("%lu", &start);
    printf("Enter end: ");
    scanf("%lu", &end);

    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned long j;

    unsigned long *tl;
    unsigned int tcount = 0;

    unsigned long *cl;
    unsigned int ccount = 0;

    int found;
    unsigned long int count3;

    tl = malloc((end - start) * sizeof(unsigned long));
    if (tl == NULL) 
    {
      perror("malloc");
      return 1;
    }  

    cl = malloc((end - start) * sizeof(unsigned long));
    if (cl == NULL) 
    {
      perror("malloc");
      return 1;
    }  


    for(i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(i + 2))
        {
            printf("twin: \t[ %lu , %lu ]\n", i, i+2);

            tl[tcount]=i;
            tcount++;
            tl[tcount]=i+2;
            tcount++;

            i++;
            count++;

        }

        if(isPrime(i) && isPrime(i + 4))
        {
            printf("cousin: [ %lu , %lu ]\n", i, i+4);

           cl[ccount]=i;
           ccount++;
           cl[ccount]=i+4;
           ccount++;

            i++;
            count2++; 

        }
    }

    printf("The number of twins: %d\n",count);
    printf("The number of cousins: %d\n",count2);

    printf("List of common twins and cousins:\n");
    count3 =  0;
    for (i=0; i < tcount; i++)
    {
      found = 0;
      for (j=0; j < ccount; j++)
      {
         if (tl[i] == cl[j])
         found = 1; 
      } 
      if (found == 1)
      {
         count3++;
         printf("%lu ",tl[i]);
      }

    }   
    printf("\n");
    printf("The number of twins and cousins: %lu\n",count3);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
$ ./ptc2
Enter start: 2
Enter end: 100
twin:   [ 3 , 5 ]
twin:   [ 5 , 7 ]
cousin: [ 7 , 11 ]
twin:   [ 11 , 13 ]
cousin: [ 13 , 17 ]
twin:   [ 17 , 19 ]
cousin: [ 19 , 23 ]
twin:   [ 29 , 31 ]
cousin: [ 37 , 41 ]
twin:   [ 41 , 43 ]
cousin: [ 43 , 47 ]
twin:   [ 59 , 61 ]
cousin: [ 67 , 71 ]
twin:   [ 71 , 73 ]
cousin: [ 79 , 83 ]
cousin: [ 97 , 101 ]
The number of twins: 8
The number of cousins: 8
List of common twins and cousins:
7 11 13 17 19 41 43 71 
The number of twins and cousins: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of bookkeeping you can do it while only calculating each prime once.

This is C#, but you'll get the idea:

```
static void CousinAndTwinPrimesUpTo(ulong max)
{
    int count = 0;
    List<ulong> primes = new List<ulong>();
    ulong prev = 0; bool wasTwin = false; bool wasCousin = false;

    for (ulong i = 3; i < max; i += 2)
    {
        bool isPrime = true;
        foreach (var p in primes)
        {
            if (i % p == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
            bool isTwin = i - 2 == prev;
            bool isCousin = i - 4 == prev;

            if (isTwin && wasCousin || isCousin && wasTwin)
            {
                count++;
            }

            primes.Add(i);
            wasTwin = isTwin; wasCousin = isCousin; prev = i;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"\nNumbers:{count}");
}
```